# DataTable.Select

Tags: c#

I have a DataTable with a column called Name.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
dc.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
dc.ColumnName = "Name";
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

I'm trying to select only the DataRows that have what's in the TextBox, but I don't know how to . Here's what I want.

```
dt.Select("string.Compare(Name.ToLower().Contains(" + textBox1.Text.ToLower() + ")");
```

Is there any way to do this with Select / should I even be attempting it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use LINQ to Dataset to do this (via [AsEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx#Y700)):

```
var results = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Name").ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()));
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe the syntax of the expression you are using is valid.  There a description of the [valid syntax here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).  To get a `contains` style operation with the `dt.Select`, you could use the `LIKE` operator.  Also you would need to set the case sensitivity to false:

```
dt.CaseSensitive = false;
dt.Select("Name LIKE '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use select

```
dt.select("Name = '"+textbox.text.trim()+"'");
```

if you want to select something similar to the textbaox then you like

```
dt.select("Name LIKE '%"+textbox.text.trim()+"%'");
```